# .Change event not changing text in td

Tags: jquery

Can somebody tell me why my `$('#cart-xchg-number').text('helleo');` not changing when i fire .change() event.

Please look at code.

```
// Exchange form tag
$('#xchg-radio-form').on('change', function () {
    var excVal = $('input[name=radioXchg]:checked', '#xchg-radio-form').val();
    var name = $("#xchg-name" + excVal).text();
    var price = parseInt($("#xchg-price" + excVal).text());
    //var num = parseInt($("#xchg-number" + excVal).val());

    //When checking insert input id to inputNum
    inputNum = excVal;

    //Disable all other inputs that are not checked
    $('input[type="number"]').attr('disabled', true);

    if (excVal == 0) {
        $('#xchg-table-pack').remove();
        obj['exchange'] = 0;
        sumNoVat(obj);

    } else {
        $('#xchg-table-pack').remove();
        $('#xchg-package').append('<table id="xchg-table-pack"><tr><th>Valgt exchange pakke</th></tr><tr><td id="cart-xchg-name"></td><td id="cart-xchg-number"></td><td id="cart-xchg-price"></td></tr></table>');

        $('#xchg-number' + excVal).prop('disabled', false);
        $('#cart-xchg-name').text(name);
        $('#cart-xchg-number').text(1).append('x');
        $('#cart-xchg-price').text(price);

        obj['exchange'] = price;
        sumNoVat(obj);
    }

});


$('input[type="number"]').change(function () {
    var num = parseInt($("#xchg-number" + inputNum).val());

    /*if (num < 0) {
        obj['number'] = num;
    }*/

    $('#cart-xchg-number').text('helleo');
});
```

Comment: 1) Verify that the event is firing. 2) Verify that the element targeted by the selector is being found.

Comment: Event is firing. only selector is problem and it works `$('#cart-xchg-number').text(1).append('x');` so it strange why didn't changing text

Comment: `var excVal = $('input[name=radioXchg]:checked', '#xchg-radio-form').val();`-> I don't think it's working properly.

Comment: Please show your html, it might help to answer.

Comment: try like this:- `$(document).on('change','input[type="number"]',function () {
    $(document).find('#cart-xchg-number').text('helleo');
});`

Comment: it's working, it's so strange i have also with this code `$('input[type="number"]').change(function () {
        var num = parseInt($("#xchg-number" + inputNum).val());*/

        /*if (num < 0) {
            obj['number'] = num;
        }*/
                       
        /*$(document).find('#cart-xchg-number').text('helleo');
    });`

and didn't work.But your code i working thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with below line.

```
var num = parseInt($("#xchg-number" + inputNum).val());
```

Either `inputNum` is not defined or out of scope. Can you please comment this line and verify, whether text box has been updated or not.

Please let me know if it is not working.

Comment: i have definded out of scope. I found the solution `$(document).on('change','input[type="number"]',function () { $(document).find('#cart-xchg-number').text('helleo'); });`